# How to keep the end point state active permanently irrespective of the end point is up or down?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

How to keep the end point state active permanently irrespective of the end point is up or down.

Answer (score 1):

If a timeout occurs that endpoint will be suspended to 30000ms(defualt).So in the suspension time if any request to that endpoint comes, esb will ignore that request.So by disabling the endpoint suspension will keep the endoint state as active always.

check this post[1] on how to disable the suspension time.

1. http://miyurudw.blogspot.com/2012/02/disable-suspension-of-wso2-esb-synapse.html

Answer (score 0):

Set the following advance endpoint options

1. Endpoint Suspend State -> Error Codes : -1
2. Endpoint Timeout State -> Error Codes : -1
3. Connection Timeout -> Action : Never Timeout

Here is a sample endpoint configuration

```
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="SampleEndpoint">
   <address uri="http://sample.com/services">
      <suspendOnFailure>
         <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
         <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
      </suspendOnFailure>
      <markForSuspension>
         <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
         <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
         <retryDelay>0</retryDelay>
      </markForSuspension>
   </address>
</endpoint>
```